# Laravel database appearing as not configured?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, openshift

So I decided to setup an Openshift server with Laravel. I ran into some complications and posted this question

[How to configure Laravel 5.2 on Openshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855570/how-to-configure-laravel-5-2-on-openshift)

I go back to it and realized I messed up a lot of stuff setting it up and really the problem was within the .env file. Now it seems like everything else is working except for my databases.

What I have been doing to test Laravel on Openshift is using the `make:auth` command, so I can test migrations and stuff like that. However, I do feel like I have setup database configurations properly, because when I ran migrations through the cli everything was setup properly (users and password_resets table showed up in the mysql database) no errors through there. Now when I try to register a user using the register page I get this error:

[image: Database Error]

[image: Database Error 2]

I've tried editing the database.php file, .env configurations, google, but I just can't find a fix. Maybe the solution is staring me in the eyes, but I'm blinder than a bat. Any help would be very much appreciated. I can provide any information needed.

Comment: did you run **php artisan migrate**?

Comment: @Evert yeah I ran the migrations that make:auth comes with and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You should set and check environment variables for database on web console.

Or you can follow the [lucho2d7/openshift-quickstart-laravel5.2](https://github.com/lucho2d7/openshift-quickstart-laravel5.2/blob/master/.openshift/.env).